# How to get Payee details in PayPal after transaction in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal SDK for payment gateway when I pay I want to get user First Name, Last Name Email and Address so, I have found this URL from PayPal Docs

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute for getting user details

Code:

```
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.description);
    NSLog(@"Details %@",completedPayment.paymentDetails);
    NSLog(@"Details 2 %@",completedPayment.confirmation);
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: but how to implement in ios, becuase it is in curl.. @EluciusFTW

Comment: where's your code? what did you try?

Comment: https://dpaste.de/z7Pa here is my code which i have implemented it's delegate method

Comment: Links can become invalid, so I pasted your code into the question.

Comment: link is working @SurvivalMachine

Comment: @VivekGoswami This site is over 7 years old, there are many, many dead links that were not always dead.

Comment: ok, but now how get i payee email when payment successfully done? @SurvivalMachine